# Breakpoints from props not working (Tailwindcss)

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a problem with my project, I don't understand why when trying to pass 'width' from props it won't work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoXzx.png

code looks like this

```
 <div className={'border-b-[1px] w-[50%] lg:' + props.width + ' text-thirdMainColor ' + props.margin }></div>
```

I will add that I also tried to add breakpoints in 'tailwind.config.js', but this did not change anything.

```
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '480px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '976px',
      xl: '1440px',
    },
```

The following form works normally.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/siSaq.png

Comment: in tailwind you can't use variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640843/is-real-that-tailwind-if-you-add-a-string-with-class-it-wont-work you need to write everything explicitely as a string. I know isn't the best but that is the reality

Comment: a solution can be writing manually a useless display none element at the start with your desired classes explicitly as a string, then you can use `+ variables` or conditionals. so tailwind will add it the css file generated and you can use it everywhere even with conditionals and + variables. I hope this helps

Comment: I solved the problem, I replaced the code with:
`<div className={'border-b-[1px] w-[50%] text-thirdMainColor ' + margin + ' ' + width}></div>`
and to props.width from w-[80%] to lg:w-[80%]

Comment: See my answer below. @LaaouatniAnas, that's incorrect.  They have an explicit mechanism for this. As described below.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Tailwind works by scanning your code and looking for things that it recognizes as classes. It then only outputs those classes into the css and everything works.  This breaks down when dynamically generate a className. :/

Despite what some believe though, (and the editorial emphasis of their own docs), this is *not* forbidden in TW.  They have a mechanism specifically to support this and other cases: `config.safelist`.  You simply list out (or define w regex) all the classes that you intend to dynamically generate in your code (or that might not appear in your codebase for some other reason).

Somewhere in your code:

```
// other logic
const cn = `${startingBP}:grid-cols-${columns} `
// other logic
```

In tailwind.config :

```js
export default {
    // ...other config stuff
    content: {
        // make sure to specify all the files you'd like tw to scan 
        files: [ 'src/**/*.tsx', './node_modules/@myorg/shared-ui/**/*.{ts,tsx}'
    },
    safelist: [
      'sm:grid-cols-1',
      'sm:grid-cols-2',
      'sm:grid-cols-3',
      'md:grid-cols-1',
      'md:grid-cols-2',
      'md:grid-cols-3',
      // etc (could also use regex)
    ]
}
```

(I actually use this a lot, since I maintain a shared framework that sometimes has to rely on logic to style things. I actually separate them into their own file, `safelist.tailwind.js` and then just import it and pass it to the config.)

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

(They recommend using whole classname literals as much as possible, but this approach is tried and true by many of us as well)